# Remote access to internal machine (ssh port-forwarding)

Tags: ssh, iptables, nat, remote-access, port-forwarding

I have a server (serv05) at work with a public ip, hosting two KVM guests - vtest1 & vtest2 - in two different private network - 192.168.122.0 & 192.168.100.0 - respectively, this way:

```
[root@serv05 ~]# ip -o addr show | grep -w inet
1: lo    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
2: eth0    inet xxx.xxx.xx.197/24 brd xxx.xxx.xx.255 scope global eth0
4: virbr1    inet 192.168.100.1/24 brd 192.168.100.255 scope global virbr1
6: virbr0    inet 192.168.122.1/24 brd 192.168.122.255 scope global virbr0
#
[root@serv05 ~]# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
192.168.100.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr1
xxx.xxx.xx.0    0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
0.0.0.0         xxx.xxx.xx.62   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

I've also setup IP FORWARDing and Masquerading this way:

```
iptables --table nat --append POSTROUTING --out-interface eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables --append FORWARD --in-interface virbr0 -j ACCEPT
```

All works up to this point. If I want to remote access *vtest1* (or vtest2) first I ssh to serv05 and then from there ssh to vtest1. Is there a way to setup a port forwarding so that *vtest1* can be accessed directly from the outside world? This is what I probably need to setup:

```
 external_ip (tcp port 4444) -> DNAT -> 192.168.122.50 (tcp port 22)
```

I know it's easily doable using a SOHO router but can't figure out how can I do that on a Linux box.

---

***Update: 1***

Now I've made ssh to listen to both of the ports:

```
[root@serv05 ssh]# netstat -tulpn | grep ssh
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xx.197:22           0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN     5092/sshd
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xx.197:4444         0.0.0.0:*         LISTEN     5092/sshd
```

and port *4444* is allowed in the iptables rules:

```
[root@serv05 sysconfig]# grep 4444 iptables
-A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4444 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.50:22 
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 4444 -j ACCEPT 
-A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 4444 -j ACCEPT
```

But I'm getting *connection refused*:

```
maci:~ santa$ telnet serv05 4444
Trying xxx.xxx.xx.197...
telnet: connect to address xxx.xxx.xx.197: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Any idea what's I'm still missing?

---

***Update: 2***

I've removed the third interface, *virbr1*, from the iptables just make the output shorter.

```
[root@serv05 sysconfig]# iptables -vL -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:53
    0     0 ACCEPT     udp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           udp dpt:67
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:67
  108  8112 ACCEPT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  lo     *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
  189 42273 ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       xxx.xxx.xx.0/24      0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:21
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:21
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:22
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:4444
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       xxx.xxx.xx.0/24      0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:80
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0           state NEW tcp dpt:80
    2    64 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24    state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4444

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 57 packets, 11124 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

The very same thing is here too, *virbr1* is intentionally removed from the output.

```
[root@serv05 sysconfig]# iptables -t nat -vL -n
Chain PREROUTING (policy ACCEPT 611 packets, 105K bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 DNAT       tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4444 to:192.168.122.50:22 

Chain POSTROUTING (policy ACCEPT 4 packets, 344 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24    masq ports: 1024-65535 
    0     0 MASQUERADE  udp  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24    masq ports: 1024-65535 
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.122.0/24    !192.168.122.0/24    
    0     0 MASQUERADE  tcp  --  *      *       192.168.100.0/24    !192.168.100.0/24    masq ports: 1024-65535 
    0     0 MASQUERADE  udp  --  *      *       192.168.100.0/24    !192.168.100.0/24    masq ports: 1024-65535 
    0     0 MASQUERADE  all  --  *      *       192.168.100.0/24    !192.168.100.0/24    

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 4 packets, 344 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

---

***Update: 3***

SSH is not listening to port 4444 anymore:

```
[root@serv05 sysconfig]# netstat -tulpn | grep ssh
tcp        0      0 xxx.xxx.xx.197:22         0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN      15231/sshd
```

The FORWARD order is fixed:

```
[root@serv05 sysconfig]# iptables -vL -n
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
[ .... ]

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            192.168.122.0/24    state RELATED,ESTABLISHED 
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 *       192.168.122.0/24     0.0.0.0/0                     
    0     0 ACCEPT     all  --  virbr0 virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           
    0     0 ACCEPT     tcp  --  eth0   *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           tcp dpt:4444 
    1    64 REJECT     all  --  *      virbr0  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  virbr0 *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-port-unreachable 
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0           reject-with icmp-host-prohibited 

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 5 packets, 612 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

but still getting connection refused:

```
maci:~ santa$ telnet serv05 4444
Trying xxx.xxx.xx.197...
telnet: connect to address xxx.xxx.xx.197: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Is there any other gray-area to cover?

Answer (score 2):

You need a NAT rule (to direct the traffic) and a regular firewall rule (to permit it).

The former will look something like

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 4444 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.122.50:22
```

The latter will look something like

```
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 4444 -j ACCEPT
```

It's up to you to make sure those come at the right point in your existing `PREROUTING` and `FORWARD` chains, and in addition you may need a second firewall rule to permit the back-half of those connections out, if you don't already have a general `ACCEPT` for `ESTABLISHED` packets.

**Edit**: the **order** of your rules is extremely important.  The right rule in the wrong place will do no good.  Could you replace the grep output above with the result of `iptables -L -n -v` and `iptables -t nat -L -n -v`?  And if you want port 4444 to be forwarded, **don't** run a local sshd also bound to that port.

**Edit 2**: and there's your problem.  The ACCEPT you've added in the FORWARD chain is line 7, but line 4 has already explicitly denied all not-previously-permitted traffic from everywhere (`*`) to `virbr0`.  You need to make arrangments for the line you've added to come **before** line 4, perhaps by adding the rule with

```
iptables -I FORWARD 4 -i eth0 -p tcp --dport 4444 -j ACCEPT
```

which will insert it at line 4, displacing the current line 4 to be line 5 (and so on).

Regarding the current sshd, I mean what I said: that you shouldn't have a daemon bound to port 4444 if you're trying to forward that port.  I don't care what other ports it's bound to, only that 4444 is a bad idea.

**Edit 3**: the machine you're testing this from, this is completely outside the serv05 system, yes?  And (after a very trying day putting Fedora 16 on several boxes) I fear you may be right, could you put a comparable `ACCEPT` rule for 4444 in the INPUT chain as well, being careful to get it **before** any REJECTs?

Comment: Thanks for you replay. I think I need a little more help. Please look in the `Update: 1` in my original post with updated info. Cheers!!

Comment: Thanks MadHatter. Updated my original post with the result as `Update: 2`. w.r.t. the ssh port, do you mean to stop ssh from listening both the ports on the same interface? cheers!!

Comment: Okay, FORWARD chain is now fixed and no daemon is bound to port 4444 any more. but still getting `connection refused` on port 4444. Anything to do with the INPUT chain as well? Result is in `Update: 3`. Cheers!!